# For creating a condtional sql query in hive based on comparison of multiple columns

Tags: hadoop, hive

Require help in forming a complex hive query. The logic is as below.
For a loc_code_pair we need to  get the unique interfaces and then provide the record with latest validation date for each unique interface

[image]

Expectation is that the data would come from the first and fourth records above:
[image]

So the pair in 1st row & 2nd row will have 1st row Val as it has latest valid_dt among the 1st & 2nd row.
Selected Values from 1st & 2nd row::
[image]

The 3rd & 4th row pair is also same as 1st & 2nd only it is in reverse order but it is same.

For 3rd & 4th row we cannot select the 3rd row Val value even if it has the latest valid_date because its INTF combination (in reverse order) is already selected in above 1st & 2nd row result.
So Selected Values from 3rd & 4th row will be::
[image]

Comment: To understand the logic: Why not row 2 & 3? Whats the order of selection? And how many rows?

Comment: row 2 & 3 is also good..any one should be picked up for a pair..but one row should have latest valid_dt & 2nd row should have different interface combination.